# List only certain files in a directory matching the word BOZO and ending with either '123' or '456'

Tags: unix, find, grep, ls

I'm trying to figure out how to get a list of file names for a file named BOZO but ending with ONLY 123 OR 456.

Files are:

BOZO12389,
BOZOand3
BOZOand456
BOZOand5
BOZOhello123

So the command should only display 'BOZOhello123' and 'BOZOand456'

I can't figure it out. I've tried all forms of LS and GREP that I can think of. The funny thing is, we tried to do it in class for about 10mins and no one could get it (including the instructor).

Comment: I can't believe that the instructor wouldn't be able to solve this for so long.

Comment: Thanks guys! We didn't spend THAT much time on it, but for some reason I instantly think 'grep' and everyone else was trying to do it with 'ls'. Therefore, it was the 1st question on the homework for that night.

Answer (score 14):

I did the following and it worked

```
ls BOZO*456 BOZO*123
```

Answer (score 12):

Using shell's globs:

```
ls BOZO*{123,456}
```

Comment: Note, this requires bash, zsh, or another advanced shell.  It is not portable and will not work in many systems' `/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 2):

Use regular expressions to help you. The command `egrep` should help, because it will allow you to use regular expressions.

You're searching for files of the kind BOZO456 and BOZO123

A period `.` is a wild card, allowing you to substitute for `<anything>`. The `*` will let you repeat it 0 or more times. By placing around 123 and 456 round brackets, you will simulate an OR.

Thus, you want any character repeated 0 or more times, followed by 123 or 456.

Example:

`egrep "BOZO.*(456|123)" data`

**Thank you to Nathan Fellman for the help and edits.**

Comment: I downvoted this because it's wrong with regard to the wild card.  In regular expressions `.` is commonly the wildcard, and `*` means "0 or more times", so this will match 'BOZ456', 'BOZOOOOOOOO123' etc...

Comment: Fixed! Thanks for the heads up, and my apologies :$

Comment: That's still not right.  This will match `BOZOa456` and `BOZOx123` but not `BOZOOO123` or even `BOZO123`.  What you need is `"BOZO.*(456|123)"

Comment: What is the `data` file?  Perhaps you forgot `ls > data` before that command?  You could do that in one command as `ls |egrep "BOZO.*(456|123)"` but that would also match BOZO1234.  Add a `$` to the end of the regex to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use *find* command :

```
    find . \( -name "BOZO*123" -o -name "BOZO*456" \)
```

Comment: This traverses children.  You want `find . -maxdepth 1 -name "BOZO*123" -o -name "BOZO*456"` (in this case, the parentheses are not necessary).

Answer (score 1):

`$ ll grep *BOZO*` should work too!

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be that hard.  The most naive way is to `ls` the directory and then grep for only what you want:

```
$ ls *BOZO* | grep -e '123$' -e '456$'
```